# Why has uvm_top disappeared?

Tags: uvm

I compiled my first IEEE 1800.2-2017 UVM code this week and was surprised to discover that `uvm_top` no longer exists. A quick search of IEEE 1800.2-2017 reveals no occurrence of "uvm_top" and a quick look at the source code reveals that it really has disappeared. Here are two workarounds:

Instead of, eg:

```
comp = uvm_top.find("*.m_agent.m_seqr"); // uvm 1.2
```

you could do:

```
comp = uvm_root::get().find("*.m_agent.m_seqr"); // IEEE 1800.2-2017
```

or, if you prefer:

```
uvm_root uvm_top = uvm_root::get();
comp = uvm_top.find("*.m_agent.m_seqr");
```

I have two questions:

i) Why did the creators of IEEE 1800.2-2017 get rid of `uvm_top`?
ii) What do they intend us to do instead? (one of those things above or something else?)

Comment: In defence of not closing this question, because it is a matter of opinion: I presume that the creators of IEEE 1800.2 got rid of `uvm_top` for a reason. I would like to know what _their reason for doing so_ is. That's not a matter of opinion, that's a fact. And, I do think the answer to this will be useful to future Googlers (because, as we all know, the needs of future askers of questions outweigh the needs of current askers of questions).

Answer (score 2):

Speculations:

1. Dogmatism that global variables are evil and should be avoided (even if in this case the variable is `const`).
2. It's easier for them to generate the class reference, because the tool can handle classes and functions, but not variables inside packages.